# Where should I handle Push Notificaiotn while using GCM ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have set up my app to work with GCM.

I have successfully added the code to integrate the GCM in my App.

Now I have two methods to handle the Push Notification:

> 1. Default Method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);
// This works only if the app started the GCM service
[[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

}
```

2. GCM Method

   ```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
   didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler {

      NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);

    // This works only if the app started the GCM service
    [[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
   // Handle the received message
   // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate   UIBackgroundFetchResult value
    // ...
    }
   ```

Now I am confused where should I Handle my `Notificaiton`.

Where should I check `application` state and call my method to handle it.

Should I have to write method in both of these methods.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with GCM but the two notification methods you listed standard UIApplicationDelegate methods and handle different scenarios.

`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is called when the app is open and you receive a plain push notification. The types that you get alerted through notification center.

`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is called when the server is letting the app know there's something to download. You check the userInfo for what to download, initiate the download and call the handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult) upon NewData/NoData/Failed

Not sure what GCM does with these two methods but with that info you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: GCM uses APNs in most cases to route notifications to your iOS application. Even when using GCM you would/should still use the methods identified here. See this sample for more: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExample/AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 0):

You should use GCM Method.

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
  fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler {
  }

In this method, You can handle your notification.
For example,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler {

    NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);
    // This works only if the app started the GCM service

    [[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){

        //app is in background

    }else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive){

        //From background to foreground (user touchs notification)
    }

    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);

    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
```